# How to get UI_element properties with appscript

Tags: ruby, rb-appscript, sourceforge-appscript

I want to write code in appscript.rb equivalent to Applescript:

```
tell App "TextEdit"
    properties of front window
end tell
```

Trying

```
te =  app("TextEdit")
puts        te.windows[1].properties
```

returns the list of property names but no value.

Thanks to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby Appscript equivalent to AppleScript’s `properties` reference has a trailing underscore: `properties_`. You will also need to use `get` to execute the query:

```
te = Appscript.app('TextEdit')
te.windows.first.properties_.get
```

The result of the last expression will be an instance of Ruby’s Hash class.

---

The title of your question mentions `UI_element`, which might indicate that you are interested in the `UI elements` objects available from *System Events*.

```
se = Appscript.app('System Events')
teap = se.application_processes['TextEdit']

# properties of frontmost UI element window
teap.windows.first.properties_.get

# properties of first-level UI elements of frontmost UI element window 
teap.windows.first.UI_elements.properties_.get
```